# PostgreSQL: Can i use tuple in where clause?

Tags: postgresql, select

Actually might be a simple question:

Given 2 tables:

```
table1: A,B,C
(A1,B1,28471),
(A1,B2,01244),
(A2,B1,1283a),
(A2,B2,82r7e);

table2: A,B,D,E,F,G
(A1,B1,18,1,6,8),
(A2,B2,18,2,3,0),
(A3,B1,18,7,1,4),
(A4,B2,18,1,9,6);
```

Will the following statement result in a the following result given the example tables:

```
SELECT E,F,G FROM table2 WHERE (A,B) IN (SELECT A,B FROM table1)
```

expected result:

```
 E F G
(1,6,8), -- (A1,B1)
(2,3,0); -- (A2,B2)
```

Can someone confirm this is a valid method to select based on tuples?

asking as the most likely next step is to UPDATE the E field by adding +5 for matching results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) instead:

```
SELECT E,F,G
FROM   table2 t2
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM table1 t1
   WHERE  (t1.A,t1.B) = (t2.A,t2.B)
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e90da9fec3333e687f27af42e11139b7)*

Equivalent and typically cheaper.
And the negation `NOT EXISTS` is not as treacherous as the discouraged (not completely equivalent) `NOT IN`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Aside, I would call `(A,B)` a ["composite type" or "row type"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION) rather than a "tuple".

Comment: In fact, `(a,b,c)` is another syntax for `ROW(a,b,c)` - `ROW` keyword is optional,  [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#id-1.5.7.24.6)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Peter Vandivier (couldnt flag his comment as the answer)

Yes it is possible:

> [What have you tried](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0e9602208507f6487f18562f47efbb89) – Peter Vandivier 12 mins ago

Comment: To be fair, I literally just copy-pasted your question onto db<>fiddle, so it feels like a self-answer is appropriate here 

Comment: Not so important here, but table aliases are a good [idea](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f9fae1c761b8da5cc08e71e5695d199c)?